# Driver [nexmo] not supported Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, autoload, laravel-6, vonage

I am using the Nexmo notifications library for Laravel and it's all of a sudden stopped working since I upgraded to Laravel 6.

Here is the error:

> (1/1) InvalidArgumentException
>   Driver [nexmo] not supported.

Any ideas why this is?

I have the library installed properly through my composer file:

`"nexmo/laravel": "^2.1.0",`

It seems to not be autoloading the library properly.

Below is my `config/app.php` file:

```
'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
        Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,

        /*
         * Package Service Providers...

         */


        Yajra\Datatables\DatatablesServiceProvider::class,
        ConsoleTVs\Charts\ChartsServiceProvider::class,
        SimpleSoftwareIO\SMS\SMSServiceProvider::class,
        Spatie\GoogleCalendar\GoogleCalendarServiceProvider::class,
        Nexmo\Laravel\NexmoServiceProvider::class,
        Propaganistas\LaravelPhone\PhoneServiceProvider::class,
        Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider::class,
        DrawMyAttention\XeroLaravel\Providers\XeroServiceProvider::class,
        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\DropboxServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\ExtendedXeroServiceProvider::class,

    ],
```

[image]

Comment: `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: @DilipHirapara Tried that already. The error still shows

Comment: There's [documentation on SMS Notifications](https://laravel.com/docs/master/notifications#sms-notifications): "_Before you can send notifications via Nexmo, you need to install the laravel/nexmo-notification-channel Composer package:_" Did you install that package? Or did you follow the [Upgrade Guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/upgrade#notifications)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package to get the notifications driver is `laravel/nexmo-notification-channel` rather than the general `nexmo/laravel` package which just enables easier use of the `nexmo/client` library in your Laravel apps.

Try installing `laravel/nexmo-notification-channel` and let us know how you go?

Comment: This did it for me thank you! I don't know why `laravel/nexmo-notification-channel` wasn't already installed, something may have changed since the upgrade in my composer.json.